# Checking input via a batch file

Tags: batch-file

I am doing user input and checking to see if they typed `n` or `y`... and it's not working because it says both either way.

Here's what I have:

```
@echo off
set /P theuserinput="Type your name: "
echo So your name is: %theuserinput%?
set /P isit="Y/N: "
echo You typed: %isit%
if (%isit% == "y") goto :saidyes
if (%isit% == "n") goto :saidno

:saidyes
echo Hooray!

:saidno
echo Aww
PAUSE
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you can add a default goto after the two if's.

Then, in both tests you have to add the quotes around %isit% and to remove the parenthesis. You may also add the /I flag to do an insensitive string comparison.

Finally, add goto after each echo to jump over the next one.

```
@echo off
set /P theuserinput="Type your name: "
echo So your name is: %theuserinput%?
set /P isit="Y/N: "
echo You typed: %isit%
if /I "%isit%" == "Y" goto :saidyes
if /I "%isit%" == "N" goto :saidno
goto :error

:saidyes
echo Hooray!
goto :end

:saidno
echo Aww
goto :end

:error
echo ERROR

:end
PAUSE
```

Comment: Ah... yes.. gotos... Hehe. Thanks! I'll mark this in two mins when I can. Thanks!

Comment: I copy pasted the above script exactly and got the same problem as the question. I removed the () and it worked. Perhaps this should not be the accepted answer.

Comment: Thanks Vik, I have not tested my code before posting it (I'm currently on Linux) and here is the result... I've just corrected the code.

Comment: Yes, I modified it a bit but I got it. :P

Answer (score 2):

Need change in syntax

Here is the modified code

```
    @echo off
set /P theuserinput="Type your name: "
echo So your name is: %theuserinput%?
set /P isit="Y/N: "
echo You typed: %isit%
if "%isit%" == "Y" GOTO saidyes
if "%isit%" == "N" GOTO saidno

:saidyes
echo Hooray!
GOTO paused

:saidno
echo Aww

:paused
PAUSE
```

....

In above example The Y/N is supposed to be capital letter only.

Comment: +1 removing the parens around the if conditional made it work for me.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few things I would do differently to this to ensure that it works properly...

First off the corrected code is the following, but at the **bottom** is my suggested code:

```
@echo off
setlocal
set theuserinput=
set /P theuserinput="Type your name: "
echo So your name is: %theuserinput%?
set /P isit="Y/N: "
echo You typed: %isit%
if '%isit%'== 'Y' goto saidyes
if '%isit%'=='N' goto saidno


:saidyes
echo Hooray!
goto end

:saidno
echo Aww
goto end

:end
pause
endlocal
exit
```

However, to make sure that you only get Y or N there are a few things I would put in...

First I would make sure that you only grab the first letter by adding:

```
IF NOT '%isit%'=='' set isit=%isit:~0,1%
```

Next I would make sure that you only have Capital letters, so you make the swap if they are lowercase, because this will actually not work in some cases if the CaSe isn't correct:

```
if '%isit%'== 'y' set isit=Y
if '%isit%'== 'Y' goto :saidyes
if '%isit%'=='n' set isit=N 
if '%isit%'=='N' goto :saidno
```

The final edit for this file could look like the following:

```
@echo off
:top
set theuserinput=
set /P theuserinput="Type your name: "
echo So your name is: %theuserinput%?
set /P isit="Y/N: "
IF NOT '%isit%'=='' set isit=%isit:~0,1%
IF '%isit%'=='y' set isit=Y
IF '%isit%'=='Y' goto saidyes
IF '%isit%'=='n' set isit=N
IF '%isit%'=='N' goto saidno
goto top

:saidyes
echo You typed: %isit%
echo Hooray!
goto end

:saidno
echo You typed: %isit%
echo Aww
goto end

:end
pause
exit
```

Answer (score 2):

Quotes are commonly misused in DOS batch files. Unlike UNIX shell scripts, the DOS batch language is not thought-out.  For example, when the `isit` variable contains quotes

```
set isit="Y"
```

then the above if-statements expand to

```
IF ""Y"" == "Y" GOTO saidyes
IF ""Y"" == "N" GOTO saidno
```

because *cmd.exe* does not remove the quotes in `"%isit%"=="Y"` before evaluating the expression.

Quotes in `isit` shall not occur with the original batch file posted here. But often you process path names in batch files, and Windows passes long file names in quotes to hide blanks. For example, as in *"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC"*. To work around this it is common practice to write if-statements so:

```
IF ["%isit%"] == ["Y"] GOTO saidyes
IF   [%isit%] == ["Y"] GOTO saidyes
IF   [%isit%] ==   [Y] GOTO saidyes
```

For `set isit="Y"` this becomes:

```
IF [""Y""] == ["Y"] GOTO saidyes
IF   ["Y"] == ["Y"] GOTO saidyes
IF   ["Y"] ==   [Y] GOTO saidyes
```

and for `set isit=Y`:

```
IF ["Y"] == ["Y"] GOTO saidyes
IF   [Y] == ["Y"] GOTO saidyes
IF   [Y] ==   [Y] GOTO saidyes
```

and for `set isit=`:

```
IF [""] == ["Y"] GOTO saidyes
IF   [] == ["Y"] GOTO saidyes
IF   [] ==   [Y] GOTO saidyes
```

which is far from being elegant, but at least works now for quoted and unquoted variables. It also works when `isit` is empty.  Oftenly batch files stop because of empty variables:

```
set x=
REM ...
IF %x% == x GOTO x
```

because now the if-statement expands to:

```
IF == x GOTO x
```

and *cmd.exe* fails. These errors are usually hard to debug.

The trick is very old; I remember using it already in MSDOS. Note that the square brackets are not evaluated by *cmd.exe*; they're just some rarely used characters. But it's just a trick. Any advanced batch script needs a dequoting-function:

```
@echo off
 setlocal EnableExtensions
 setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
 REM ...
 set /P isit="Y/N: "
 call :dequote isit
 REM ...
 IF "!isit!" == "Y" GOTO saidyes
 IF "!isit!" == "N" GOTO saidno
 REM ...
 goto done

:dequote
 for /f "delims=" %%A in ('echo %%%1%%') do set %1=%%~A
 goto :eof

:done
```

The `deqote`-subroutine removes any double quotes around the variable name passed to the function.

After dequoting the `[]`-trick is not required anymore. Note also the use of `!` instead of `%`. The exclamation marks force *cmd.exe* to reexpand `isit`.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the code somewhat to help fix your problem. Instead of goto :(function) you just say goto (function)

```
@echo off
set /P theuserinput=Type your name: 
echo So your name is: %theuserinput%?
set /p isit=Y/N: 
echo You typed: %isit%
if %isit% == "y" goto saidyes
if %isit% == "n" goto saidno

:saidyes
echo Hooray!

:saidno
echo Aww
pause
```

Comment: But it has no effect, as both variants are allowed